# Making 2 loops run in parallel

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have a task on one of my work sheets asking me to add OpenMP directives to make both of these loops run in parallel.

```
{
 for (i = ; i < N; i += )
{
 D[i] = x * A[i] + x * B[i];
}

 for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
 C[i] = c * D[i];
 }
}
```

I made a C file to add the Openmp directives

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h.>

#define THREADS 4
#define N 10

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i;
double A[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, B[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, C[N], D[N];
const double x = 5;
const double z = 5;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(THREADS)

 for (i = 0; i < N; i += 10)
{
 D[i] = z * A[i] + z * B[i];
 printf("part 1 Thread %d is doing iteration %d: %d \n", omp_get_thread_num(
),i, D[i]);
}
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(THREADS)
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
 C[i] = x * D[i];
 printf("part 2 Thread %d is doing iteration %d: %d \n", omp_get_thread_num(
),i, C[i]);
 } 



return 0;
}
```

I get part 1 do one iteration and then part 2 do all iterations, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: First, there is a bonus "." in <math.h.>. Then @Mark Setchell, there is an implicit barrier after an omp for, so there is no issue there. More likely the issue is that variables are not declared in the smallest scope so become implicitly shared when they should be private to each thread. (There are other perversities here too; Why are there two loops at all? Why two parallel regions? Why force the number of threads?, ...) but those are not correctness issues, merely ones of sanity :-)

Comment: @JimCownie Many thanks for the *"heads-up"* and tagging me. I will delete my earlier comment so as not to mislead others with my own inaccurate perceptions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 only do 1 iteration because there is only 1 iteration to do:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(THREADS)
for (i = 0; i < N; i += 10)
```

where `N` expands to 10 in line 7:

```c
#define N 10
```

A second iteration never happens because is out of loop's range